# Temporarily disable bluetooth device in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, bluetooth

Is there a way to disable (not un-pair) a Bluetooth device in Windows 8.1?

The reason I ask is that I often pair to a speaker system but like to switch to headphones from time to time. Disabling Bluetooth is not an option since I also use a Bluetooth mouse with my laptop.

**Solution**

Following @Dean Meehan's suggestions I ended up getting this working by going into the Sound panel and disconnecting the Bluetooth device which in my case was a Sony SRS-BTX500.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage any device from the devices menu in control panel. Including disabling devices, which will just "grey" out the device, which can be re-enabled using the same process.

1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Search. (If
   you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen,
   move the mouse pointer down, and then click Search.)
2. Enter Devices and Printers in the search box, and tap or click
   Devices and Printers.
3. Press and hold or right-click a device, and then click disable.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the option to disable but can Disable it as a playback device under the Sound menu which still maintains the bluetooth link I think. I think un-pairing is the only way I am going to be able to get this working.

Comment: I think I will have to play around with this as I've noticed now there is a 'disconnect' option present.